# What is priority in mapconfig_for_cars.xml of osm2pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I am new user to pgrouting. I wonder what the meaning of "priority" value means? By default, the values are 1, 1.05, 1.15, 1.5, etc. How to calculate it and why it becomes a value. Also, is this value the same as the penalty value that can be used in routing queries with Dijkstra?

Answer (score 1):

When you import OSM data with osm2pgrouting several tables are created. One of these tables is `osm_way_classes` and it may look like this:

```sql
routing=# SELECT * FROM osm_way_classes;
 class_id | type_id |       name        | priority | default_maxspeed 
----------+---------+-------------------+----------+------------------
      201 |       2 | lane              |        1 |               50
      204 |       2 | opposite          |        1 |               50
      203 |       2 | opposite_lane     |        1 |               50
[...]
      305 |       3 | grade5            |        1 |               50
(36 rows)
```

You can specify a value for `priority` in your `mapconfig.xml` file and it will be written into that table when you import data. And you can change that value any time later in that table. The `priority` field is also added to the `ways` table and you can change the value as well.

You can see the `priority` attribute as a suggestion and you can make use of it in your query as part of your cost function. pgRouting minimizes costs, and to find the shortest path for example you would take the `length` of a road segment as cost.

Now, if you want to prioritize certain road segments, you had to decrease their costs, and you can do this with a factor using `priority`.

For example, you could make your cost function be `length * priority`. In this case lower priority value lowers the cost of a road segment and higher priority value makes it more expensive, so the shortest path function will likely follow road segments with smaller priority value.

How you build your query and cost function is up to you. You can just ignore the `priority` attribute and create your own schema.

I would suggest you this chapter of the pgRouting workshop to learn how you can manipulate the costs: https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/chapters/advanced.html#cost-manipulations

Comment: thank you for your answer dkastl. I understand now how this works. But But if I change one of the priority values to 0 will that path not be traversed by routing?

Comment: The atttribute is just a column in the database and will not be used at all, if it's not part of the cost function of your query. And how it is applied in the cost function is your decision. You could have a cost like `cost + priority * cost`. Then the cost increases with higher priority and with the least cost if priority is `0`.